Whenever I try to run my flutter project on ios simulator it gives following error after configuring firebase to my project (flutterfire configure)?
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/darwin`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_player_avfoundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player_avfoundation/darwin`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.16.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.23.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update



Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A BoringSSL-GRPC
  A Firebase
  A FirebaseAnalytics
  A FirebaseAppCheckInterop
  A FirebaseAuth
  A FirebaseAuthInterop
  A FirebaseCore
  A FirebaseCoreExtension
  A FirebaseCoreInternal
  A FirebaseFirestore
  A FirebaseFirestoreInternal
  A FirebaseInstallations
  A FirebaseSharedSwift
  A FirebaseStorage
  A Flutter
  A GTMSessionFetcher
  A GoogleAppMeasurement
  A GoogleUtilities
  A PromisesObjC
  A RecaptchaInterop
  A abseil
  A cloud_firestore
  A firebase_analytics
  A firebase_auth
  A firebase_core
  A firebase_storage
  A gRPC-C++
  A gRPC-Core
  A image_picker_ios
  A leveldb-library
  A nanopb
  A path_provider_foundation
  A sqflite
  A url_launcher_ios
  A video_player_avfoundation

Downloading dependencies

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:538:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:258:in `block in download_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:257:in `download_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Cloning into '/var/folders/46/s2c_zhn95d1bhzzr8v5f0j300000gn/T/d20240411-57447-x9x3b2'...
error: 5736 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
     fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
I tried updating cocoapods and clearing cache
